# Constraint that allows only 10 instances of the string "username"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add a constraint to my database table so that the string "username" can only be entered into a certain column a max of 10 times. Is this possible?

I'm using ms sql server.

Comment: I see this fits more for business logic, so I would handle it from application rather than database

Comment: Do you mean to count "username" in the contents of a text column value? Like counting a keyword in a text for CEO, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `AFTER` trigger `UPDATE/INSERT`:

**[SQLFiddleDEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fa1c1e)**

```
CREATE TABLE tab(col NVARCHAR(100));

CREATE TRIGGER trg_tab
ON tab
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
 IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab WHERE col = 'username') > 10
 ROLLBACK;

INSERT INTO tab(col)
VALUES ('username'), ('username'), ('username'), ('username'),
       ('username'), ('username'), ('username'), ('username'),
       ('username'),('username');

INSERT INTO tab(col)
VALUES ('username');  

/* The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted. */
```

Or use `SCALAR FUNCTION` and `CHECK` constraint:

**[SQLFiddleDemo2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aeba0/1/0)**

```
CREATE TABLE tab(col NVARCHAR(100));

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckFunction()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab WHERE col = 'username')
END;

ALTER TABLE tab
ADD CONSTRAINT chkRowCount CHECK (dbo.CheckFunction() <= 10 );

INSERT INTO tab(col)
VALUES ('username'), ('username'), ('username'), ('username'),
       ('username'), ('username'), ('username'), ('username'),
       ('username'),('username');

INSERT INTO tab(col)
VALUES ('username');  

/* The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "chkRowCount".
 The conflict occurred in database "db_6_34d5e", table "dbo.tab". */
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on the table. some thing like this

```
create trigger LimitTable
on YourTableToLimit
after insert
as
    declare @tableCount int
    select @tableCount = Count(*)
    from YourTableToLimit

    if @tableCount > 50
    begin
        rollback
    end
go
```